# Crear usuarios en firebase en angular 4

Tags: firebase, angular

En **firebase** puedo crear usuarios en un registro

```
AngularFireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
```

Pero al utilizar ese método el usuario actual cambia y se agrega a la sesión automaticamente, pero lo que quiero es crear muchos usuarios al tiempo sin perder el que ya inicio sesion ¿como se puede hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas utilizar es el sdk admin de firebae: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

De manera que ese código lo manejes en tu back-end con NodeJs, Java o Python. La documentación está muy clara.

De ahí lo que harías sería exponer un método en un servicio REST por ejemplo que mandes llamar desde tu aplicación Angular Front-End para gestionar tus usuarios de manera masiva.